# Retriving values of a checkbox

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have created a GetEmployeeDetails.jsp page wherein i take details like name,age,hobbies etc.
and the from there i forward to a sevlet whcich retrives those values using getParameter()..
my problem is 'Hobbies' in the form uses checkboxes like programming,singing,sleeping..when i forward this page to a servlet i could retrive those values and set to session object like this :

```
String[] hobbies = request.getParameterValues("Hobbies");
        for(int i=0;i<hobbies.length;i++){
        session.setAttribute("hobbies", hobbies[i]);
        }
```

but the problem rises when i want to show these employee details in next jsp page i.e ShowEmpDetails.jsp ..i could not retrive all values of session attribute "hobbies".. it gives me only last value of checkbox that i have checked..
i used this code in my ShowEmpDetails.jsp page..

```
your hobbies:&nbsp;<%=session.getAttribute("hobbies")%><br>
```

please guide me..

Answer (score 0):

you are overwriting the session attribute "hobbies". It contains just a single value (the last setted), not the entire list.

Comment: yaa i got that ..but whats the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Overwriting `hobbies` value.

Try

```
 session.setAttribute("hobbies"+i, hobbies[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you are saving just the last value of hobbies...

To save all you can set as session variable an ArrayList:

```
String[] hobbies = request.getParameterValues("Hobbies");
         ArrayList<String> aux=new ArrayList<>();
         for(int i=0;i<hobbies.length;i++){
             aux.add(hobbies[i]);
         }
         session.setAttribute("hobbies", aux);
```

Comment: @user2412380 Then I advise you to choose as correct answer... Doing that you don't receive more unnecessary answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

you are overwriting `hobbies` value.

You can set these values in `JSON` format or simply re-structure these values like

```
String str=new String(" ");
for(int i=1;i<hobbies.length;i++)
        str=str + "," +hobbies[i];
session.setAttribute("hobbies", str);
```